# Veracity in terms of accuracy

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I want one word which indicates "Something with great veracity". Here, the emphasis of veracity is more towards "accuracy" than "truth".

It's a thing, an instrument that has good veracity.

I want to use this word as a name for such an instrument.

Comment: Dipan: Your question's title asks for "**someone** having veracity," but your closing statement mentions that "it's a **thing**, an instrument."  Which is it?  Are you looking for a word that describes an instrument, or a person?  (If the former, you should change "someone" to "something" in your title and opening sentence. If the latter, you should probably remove or restate your last sentence.)

Comment: Do you want a word meaning "an accurate instrument/person" or one meaning "a veracious instrument/person"? They're not at all the same thing.

Comment: Btw, what exactly do you mean by *veracity*? What is the quality that you are looking to signify? You may not expect us to speculate on that, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Senses of *[veridical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/veridical#Adjective)*, the only word I thought of when I read the question, include  “True” and
“Pertaining to an experience, perception, or interpretation that accurately represents reality”.  However, for a product name one is not limited to real words.   I think you would do well to consult translation dictionaries; foreign words may carry more cachet and may be more distinctive.  Also look at the etymologies of words of interest; for example, regarding *veridical* [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=veridical) says “1650s, from L. *veridicus*, from *verum* ‘truth,’ neuter of *verus* ‘true’ (see very) + *dic-*, stem of *dicere*  ‘to speak’ (see *diction*)”; from which you might be led to consider combinations involving *verum* or *verus*.  And so forth with words suggested in other answers.  [Note, “naming” is off-topic in  ELU (see fifth item in second bullet list of [faq](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq)), so if you want specific advice about product names, you must ask elsewhere.]

Answer (score 6):

In the biomedical world, tests (one type of *measurement instrument*), are often described as *sensitive* and *specific*. The sensitivity and specificity are expressed as percentages. An **accurate** test is one that has, for example, *a sensitivity of 95% and a specificity of 97%*.

While *veracity* and *accuracy* may be sometimes synonyms, I wouldn't describe the results of a scientific instrument's (hardware) measurements, or of a pathology test (biochemical), or of an IQ test (software), or of a political preference poll (software) as **honest** (which is what **veracity** implies, but as **accurate** and **trustworthy** in the sense that it usually doesn't give false-positives or false-negatives.

I think that **accurate** is an excellent choice for biochemical and software instruments, but if it's hardware, **a precision instrument** (i.e., **precise**) is also an excellent choice.

Comment: *Accuracy* and *precision* have [distinct definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision): "A measurement system can be accurate but not precise, precise but not accurate, neither, or both... In the fields of science, engineering, industry and statistics, the accuracy[1] of a measurement system is the degree of closeness of measurements of a quantity to that quantity's actual (true) value. The precision[1] of a measurement system, also called reproducibility or repeatability, is the degree to which repeated measurements under unchanged conditions show the same results.[2]"

Comment: @JLG: Excellent comment. +1 Terminology is always a problem. When I edit, I always use the dictionary to verify the exact meanings of technical terms. Even when I think I know the meaning, I want to check to make sure that I'm right.

Comment: The difficulty is that the non-scientific community, and quite often the scientific community when not in the lab, use the terms in their nore general, synonymous, senses. This can lead to misunderstandings when the different registers are not explained.

Answer (score 2):

In testing, the usefulness of a measuring technique (including instrumental measurements) are characterized by two principal criteria, *validity* and *reliability*. See [this discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_%28statistics%29).

> *Validity* of an assessment is the degree to which it measures what it is supposed to measure.
>
> *reliability* . . . is the extent to which a measurement gives results that are consistent.

Additional criteria, largely relating to precision are *sensitivity and specificity*

> a test [or instrument administering a test] needs to be *sensitive* enough to detect the relevant problem [or phenomenon] if it is present (and therefore avoid too many false negative results), but *specific* enough not to respond to other things (and therefore avoid too many false positive results

Answer (score 1):

You could simply say the instrument is *accurate*.  From NOAD:

> **accurate** (adj.) 1 (of information, measurements, statistics, etc.) correct in all details; exact : *accurate information about the illness is essential*.
>   • (of an instrument or method) capable of giving such information : *an accurate thermometer*.

If the word accurate isn't "flashy" enough for you, though, I'd recommend *precise*:

> **precise** (adj.) 
>   marked by exactness and accuracy of expression or detail

One other choice: the noun form of *precise* (i.e., *precision*), can also be used as an adjective, when referring to instruments:

> **precision** (n.)
>   the quality, condition, or fact of being exact and accurate : *the deal was planned and executed with military precision*.
>   • [as adj. ] marked by or adapted for accuracy and exactness : *a precision instrument*.

As a footnote, the usage of the term *precision instruments* seems to have really taken off around WWII; there's an [interesting Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=precise+instruments%2Cprecision+instruments%2Caccurate+instruments&year_start=1880&year_end=2005&corpus=0&smoothing=2), if you're curious.

Comment: I thought it was for a person not device. Did you read the title?

Comment: @Noah: I thought the last sentence overrode the title. Could be an error on my part, but I think the O.P. is a non-native who meant _something_, not _someone_. I've posted a comment requesting clarification.

Comment: I'd echo the comment of @JLG about accuracy versus precision. A precise watch might measure hundredths of a second. An accurate watch might keep time to within one second a day. While a watch may be both precise and accurate, precision does not imply accuracy, nor does accuracy imply precision. And despite the rise of "precision instruments," I think that "accurate" is more what the OP seeks.

Comment: @rajah9: This is a classic case of an O.P. asking too vague a question. Sure, a watch might be an instrument; so might a spectrometer, or an altimeter, or an IUPC. Is the O.P. writing a marketing brochure for the maker of scientific instruments used in research labs? Describing a highly accurate watch used by the main character of fictional spy novel?  Really, we don't have a clue, because all we have to work with is, _I want one word which indicates "Something with great veracity"._  I'm not sure if the O.P. wants "accurate" or "precision" – which is precisely why I offered both.

Comment: Fair enough, @J.R. And so much better than the response I didn't send: "What is truth?" Instruments don't tell truth; they reflect different levels of the electromagnetic spectrum, barometric pressure, or pressure within the uterus (to site your examples). Even if Mark Twain didn't say it, this is appropriate: "Figures never lie, but liars often figure."

Answer (score 0):

> **Scrupulous** (of a person or process) diligent, thorough, and extremely attentive to details: *the research has been carried out with scrupulous attention to detail.*

And *veracious* itself could be used, which is the adjective form of *veracity*.

Comment: Scope for a pun on *voracious* there, I think.

Answer (score 0):

*Exact* can be used as an adjective [meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exact) "characterized by accurate measurements or inferences with small margins of error; not approximate; operating with very great precision."

Also, the word [*true*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/true) itself has more than a dozen definitions, a few of which are: "reliable, accurate" and "free from error" and "conforming to definitive criteria."